# How to keep points inside a polygon and remove other points?

Tags: python, algorithm, polygon

I have a 3d point cloud as shown in the first figure. I want to detect and draw polygons around all the boundaires present in the point cloud, I mean main polygon that represents the outer boundaries of the point cloud and another polygons that defines the inner boundaries as shown in figure 2. I tried convex hull but it only gets points representing the outer boundaries. The idea is that I want polygons defining all the boundaries such that later on if I have any points lying inside the inner boundaries or outside the outer boundaries I can remove them. Any ideas how I can do that in python?[image][image]

Comment: I would start here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-edge-detection-using-pillow

Comment: @Hardest: these methods are used on images and are completely irrelevant for point clouds. Don't send people in dead-ends if you don't have the know-how.

Comment: Have a look at the Alpha-shapes. https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_2/index.html

Comment: Then draw a circle or a square centered in every point with range / diagonal proportional to the avg distance of some random points and you will get an image which is processable with edge detection algos